# Mypy Incompatible types in assignment when relying on dynamic access, expression has type "object"

Tags: python, mypy

I would like to know why this isn't correct. Here is a small example that highlights the error:

```py
import typing

kwargs: dict = {}
region, city, state = kwargs.get('region'), kwargs.get('city'), kwargs.get('state')

ordered_params = [city, state, region]
last = None
valid_depth = 0
while ordered_params:
    last = ordered_params.pop()
    if last is None:
        break
    valid_depth += 1

if any(p is not None for p in ordered_params):
    raise ValueError("must specify everything")

filter_requirements = [
    (
        'region', []
    ),
    (
        'state', [
            ('region', region),
        ]
    ), (
        'city', [
            ('region', region),
            ('state', state),
        ]
    ), (
        'name', [
            ('region', region),
            ('state', state),
            ('city', city),
        ]
    )
]

main_select: str
required_where: typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, str]]
main_select, required_where = filter_requirements[valid_depth]
```

The last line says that the expression has a type of "object", but runs just fine.

Comment: what error are you getting exactly? Proviide the error message as formatted text in the question itself

Comment: In any case, the error is because `filter_requirements` type is inferred as `builtins.list[Tuple[builtins.str, builtins.object]]` which makes sense since *you didn't annotate it as anything*. So when you try to assign to `required_where`, which you *did annotate*, it cannot accept `object` it needs `typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, str]]` or a subtype.

Comment: So, it seems like you just want to annotate `filter_requirement: typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, str]]]]` but then you are going to have to narrow the types for `region`, `state` and `city`

Comment: Although frankly, I would change your approach, given what you seem to be trying to do. Why is `filter_requirements` a `list` of `tuples`? What are the actual inputs you expect to get?

Comment: The `str` type annotations in the real script are sqlalchemy instrumented attributes. It's a list of required fields paired with their values as provided by the user, which will be used to filter results based on the scope of the query.

Answer (score 0):

As [@juanpa-arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) mentioned in the comments, the use of unpacking to associate typing annotations isn't correct. The variable which contains the full structure needs to be annotated, and the later destructuring will correctly pick up on the type information.

```py
RequiredWhereClause = typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, str]]
filter_requirements: typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, RequiredWhereClause]] = [
    (
        'region', []
    ),
    (
        'state', [
            ('region', region),
        ]
    ), (
        'city', [
            ('region', region),
            ('state', state),
        ]
    ), (
        'name', [
            ('region', region),
            ('state', state),
            ('city', city),
        ]
    )
]

main_select, required_where = filter_requirements[valid_depth]
```

Note that this will highlight the use of `.get()` without a second argument to coerce the return type of dict lookup misses. Changing these to an empty string will fix that.

```py
kwargs: dict = {}
region, city, state = kwargs.get('region', ''), kwargs.get('city', ''), kwargs.get('state', '')
```

Or, change the second argument of the `RequiredWhereClause`'s tuple to `typing.Optional[str]`.